# How to use boost json when exceptions are disabled?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I use a library which cannot use exceptions.

I want to use boost json in my project.

I see that it can work without exceptions, but I get this error:

```
/home/pache/Boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/json/detail/value_to.hpp:662:9: error: cannot use 'throw' with exceptions disabled
        throw;
```

I tried to define
`BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS`
and use `-fno-exceptions`
but that doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like a bug, it's fixed in 1.83

Answer (score 0):

Within the implementation of `value_to` there is a `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.
You could use the non-throwing version of `value_to` called `try_value_to`. It returns a `std::variant` which may or may not hold a value. You would have to verify whether the returned `std::variant` holds a value.

`try_value_to` documentation
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__try_value_to.html

`value_to` implementation
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/json/value_to.hpp

Comment: thanks, I get error when only include header.It can work in 1.83.